# How to disable text overwrite mode in Netbeans (CentOS)?

Tags: keyboard, centos, netbeans

Everytime I type some text, it is overwriting what I have typed. I assume that the mode is set to overwriting,

I want to insert the text not overwrite it, but I can't disable it because my insert key is mixed up with my delete key so everytime I enter insert to disable the overwrite mode, it just delete what I type.

So how to disable this?

I'm using centOS.. and it seems that my problem is only related to Netbeans because when I type here, it is set to insert mode.. but in Netbeans, it just overwrites the codes! help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about CENTos, but I know that there are 2 insert keys on your keyboard. The second one is on the keypad at the right. Disable numlock, then press 0. This should turn insert mode on or off.

Otherwise, google for programs called "key remappers". If this is some kind of linux, this link might have useful info:
http://www.linuxscrew.com/2008/09/15/faq-how-to-disableremap-a-keyboard-key-in-linux/

Answer (score 0):

Check the file `/etc/sysconfig/keyboard`  and check the line `KEYBOARD=xx`. Make sure the xx is appropriate for your keyboard layout.

You can set up the language and keyboard using the commands `system-config-language` and `system-config-keyboard`.

If the standard keyboard layouts don't match your keyboard, you can make smaller changes (with more work on your part) by reading the output of `man showkey`, `man loadkeys` and `man keymaps`.